# Complement a DNA sequence

Tags: r, replace, bioinformatics, genetics, complement

Suppose I have a DNA sequence. I want to get the complement of it. I used the following code but I am not getting it. What am I doing wrong ?

```
s=readline()
ATCTCGGCGCGCATCGCGTACGCTACTAGC
p=unlist(strsplit(s,""))
h=rep("N",nchar(s))
unlist(lapply(p,function(d){
for b in (1:nchar(s)) {    
    if (p[b]=="A") h[b]="T"
    if (p[b]=="T") h[b]="A"
    if (p[b]=="G") h[b]="C"
    if (p[b]=="C") h[b]="G"
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Use `chartr` which is built for this purpose:

```
> s
[1] "ATCTCGGCGCGCATCGCGTACGCTACTAGC"
> chartr("ATGC","TACG",s)
[1] "TAGAGCCGCGCGTAGCGCATGCGATGATCG"
```

Just give it two equal-length character strings and your string. Also vectorised over the argument for translation:

```
> chartr("ATGC","TACG",c("AAAACG","TTTTT"))
[1] "TTTTGC" "AAAAA"
```

Note I'm doing the replacement on the string representation of the DNA rather than the vector. To convert the vector I'd create a lookup-map as a named vector and index that:

```
> p
 [1] "A" "T" "C" "T" "C" "G" "G" "C" "G" "C" "G" "C" "A" "T" "C" "G" "C" "G" "T"
[20] "A" "C" "G" "C" "T" "A" "C" "T" "A" "G" "C"
> map=c("A"="T", "T"="A","G"="C","C"="G")
> unname(map[p])
 [1] "T" "A" "G" "A" "G" "C" "C" "G" "C" "G" "C" "G" "T" "A" "G" "C" "G" "C" "A"
[20] "T" "G" "C" "G" "A" "T" "G" "A" "T" "C" "G"
```

Answer (score 13):

The [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) package [Biostrings](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html) has many useful functions for this sort of operation. Install once:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("Biostrings")
```

then use

```
library(Biostrings)
dna = DNAStringSet(c("ATCTCGGCGCGCATCGCGTACGCTACTAGC", "ACCGCTA"))
complement(dna)
```

Answer (score 9):

To complement, in both upper and lower case, you can use `chartr()`:

```
n <- "ACCTGccatGCATC"
chartr("acgtACGT", "tgcaTGCA", n)
# [1] "TGGACggtaCGTAG"
```

To take it a step further and reverse complement the nucleotide sequence, you can use the following function:

```
library(stringi)

rc <- function(nucSeq)
  return(stri_reverse(chartr("acgtACGT", "tgcaTGCA", nucSeq)))

rc("AcACGTgtT")
# [1] "AacACGTgT"
```

Answer (score 5):

There is also a package seqinr

```
library(seqinr)
comp(seq) # gives complement
rev(comp(seq)) # gives the reverse complement
```

Biostrings has a much smaller memory profile, but seqinr is nice also because you can choose the case of the bases (including mixed) and change them to anything you want, for example if you want a mix of T and U in the same sequence. Biostrings forces you to have either T or U.

Comment: I'm not sure this is entirely accurate: comp("u") returns NA

Comment: @TomKelly your sequence has to be in the form of a vector of character, each character of length 1.
What JeremyS forgot to mention is that you need to first cut your sequence if it is one single character.
to rewrite, this should work: `comp(s2c(seq))`

Comment: @YoannPageaud I've actually added support for strings (of any length) as a function here: https://github.com/TomKellyGenetics/tktools/blob/master/R/utils.R#L48..L171

Comment: @YoannPageaud No, the issue is that "U" is not supported. The same input with "A" or "T" works.
```
> library(seqinr)
> comp("t")
[1] "a"
> comp("u")
[1] NA
> comp("a")
[1] "t"
> comp(c("u"))
[1] NA
> comp(c("U"))
[1] NA
> comp(c("T"))
[1] "a"
> comp(s2c("u"))
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sapply(p, switch,  "A"="T", "T"="A","G"="C","C"="G")
  A   T   C   T   C   G   G   C   G   C   G   C   A   T   C   G   C   G   T 
"T" "A" "G" "A" "G" "C" "C" "G" "C" "G" "C" "G" "T" "A" "G" "C" "G" "C" "A" 
  A   C   G   C   T   A   C   T   A   G   C 
"T" "G" "C" "G" "A" "T" "G" "A" "T" "C" "G"
```

If you do not want the complementary names, you can always strip them with `unname`.

```
unname(sapply(p, switch,  "A"="T", "T"="A","G"="C","C"="G") )
 [1] "T" "A" "G" "A" "G" "C" "C" "G" "C" "G" "C" "G" "T" "A" "G" "C" "G" "C"
[19] "A" "T" "G" "C" "G" "A" "T" "G" "A" "T" "C" "G"
>
```

Comment: that's nice I never knew the `switch` function.

Comment: Seems almost custom built for this purpose.

Comment: Custom built by someone with no aesthetic sense, perhaps! :)

Comment: The switch function seemed to be the R/S equivalent of the Pascal case function as least as I remember from 40 years ago. I usually have to search for a while in the help pages to find it. Seems like the should be a link from the ?’if’ page.

Comment: Damn. There is a link on the ?if page.

Answer (score 1):

Here a answer using base r.  Written with a horrible formatting to make things clear and to keep it as a one-liner. It supports upper and lower cases.

```
revc = function(s){
       paste0(
           rev(
            unlist(
             strsplit(
                chartr("ATGCatgc","TACGtacg",s)
                      , "")                        # from strsplit
                   )                               # from unlist
               )                                   # from rev
             , collapse='')                        # from paste0
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've generalised the solution `rev(comp(seq))` with the `seqinr` package:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("TomKellyGenetics/tktools")
tktools::revcomp(seq)
```

This version is compatible with string inputs and is vectorised to handle list or vector input of multiple strings. The output class should match the input, including cases and types. This also support inputs containing "U" for RNA and RNA output sequences.

```
> seq <- "ATCTCGGCGCGCATCGCGTACGCTACTAGC"
> revcomp(seq)
[1] "GCTAGTAGCGTACGCGATGCGCGCCGAGAT"

> seq <- c("TATAAT", "TTTCGC", "atgcat")
> revcomp(seq)
  TATAAT   TTTCGC   atgcat 
 "ATTATA" "GCGAAA" "atgcat"
```

See the [manual](https://rdrr.io/github/TomKellyGenetics/tktools/man/revcomp.html) or the [TomKellyGenetics/tktools](https://github.com/TomKellyGenetics/tktools) github package repository.